# using Mixamo/adobe fuse, Makehuman, and blender together

Tags: animation, texturing, rigging, export, import

This question is fairly simple, i recently found Fuse and decided to try it to see if i could animate and create characters easier than i can with blender (because i'm not great at blender) or Makehuman.

The question is, how can i get models with the textures, correct orientation, correct scale, and animations to import/export properly (mainly from fuse or Make human to blender for adjustments then back again.)? 
  All information i can find is simply mixamo to blender but those result in models being giant, facing incorrectly (on back) and not having rigging in properly. i need to be able to use animations and textures primarily.

Comment: In 2.77a importing fbx seems to work.

Comment: it seems obj works but it takes some work to make sure that everything actually works properly, but going from blender back to makehuman or fuse is mostly not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mhx2 importer for blender: its an addon you need for make human...works great. For Fuse, they don't import well, but do import into UE4 fine so probably just a blender thing, I do my Mixamo/Fuse touchups in Unreal and Makehuman in Blender.